# Steam miscalculating disk size?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, games, steam

So I have 2 disks, one with 27gb remaining, and other one of 1tb that is empty.

I'm mounting the 1tb disk in `/mnt/big-drive`, and I've added a steam library in `/mnt/big-drive/Games`, via `Steam > Settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders`.

When I try to install a game, it gives me the option to select the new folder, but the space available keeps the same: 27gb, and as the game is bigger than that, I can't install it.

What could I do?

Edit:

Please take a look on a few screenshots, as requested:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 3]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Here, for some reason it just displays `Local drive (/)` instead of `Local drive (/mnt/big-drive/Games)`. I've already double checked if I selected it correctly.

Comment: You could must move the whole .steam directory (optionally rename it) to the new disk, and replace it with a link (named .steam).

Comment: @ubfan1 Quite the radical and unneeded approach. Steam allows additional locations for games installations and it **should** show the correct available space for each one when explicitly selected prior to the installation. That this one isn't doing that - according to the OP's report of which I'm very much skeptical, having done it myself for many years and dozens of different machines and never experienced anything like this - is no reason to move everything to another partition. Steam should be troubleshot instead.

Comment: @EnzoDtz Do you have read/write/execute permissions in the additional partition who's mount point is, according to you, `/mnt/big-drive`? If so then the next question is are you sure you're selecting it before committing to the installation? Can you post a screenshot showing the correct destination selected with the incorrect available space?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've edited the post with the screenshots you've asked, please take a look, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. It's unusual. In my current PC I also have one additional location mounted under /mnt and it shows correctly albeit as (), different then the main default one (/). Your screenshot shows two that seems to be exactly the same one. I suggest you remove and re-add the additional library folder.